# Why am I getting a status 404 with jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using Firefox and am trying to access a json file locally. The javascript file and test.json are in the same folder. I get an undefined for my url.

#### My folder structure is:

```
root
|- js
| |-script.js
| |-test.json
|- index.html
```

#### script.js

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'test.json', 
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    error: function(data) {
    console.log(data.url);
    console.log('error', data);
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('success', data);
  },
  complete: function() {
    console.log('done');
  }
});
```

#### test.json

```
[{
  "abc": "testing"
 }, {
  "efg": "testing"
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks fine

But `url: 'test.json',`
Should be `url: 'js/test.json',`

Because index.html accesses test.json from parent directory and not JS directory

Comment: Thanks, I never thought about it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Change the URL with respect to `index.html`.

```
url: 'js/test.json',
```

This is not like CSS, the paths should be relative to the page the script gets executed.